# Best way to store temporary data in .Net Core-based project running in a Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a .Net Core service running in Docker container (using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim as base image). I want to store a temporary value (e.g. last checked record id) somewhere in the container to restore that after container/host machine reboot. In Windows machine I would use registry as storage, but in the Docker container is there a way to achieve that without using DB or temp files?

Comment: No. The design of containers is that they are stateless and ephemeral. You either need to include values in your image (which will be lost upon recreation) or bind a volume.

Comment: If you consider registry as a separate "system", on similar lines think of another container which can hold the temporary value. e.g. redis.

Comment: Thank you for insights. Finally I came up with mounting container's /tmp directory into host's directory and storing last checked id in /tmp like that: docker run --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/container,target=/tmp